# jquery UI draggable droppable nested elements

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, draggable

I'm trying to create a draggable and droppable interface where you drop an element on the page and then using the same menu bar you can drag another clone of the element in to the element you previously dropped and so on.

I am using the Bootstrap grid as the containers.

I have two problems. The element dropped is then not sortable. 
I can't drag and drop into newly created containers.

Below is the html and then jquery

```
<div class="MainWrapper ui-droppable DocPreview col-md-9 col-lg-6">
    <div>
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='column ui-droppable col-md-6'></div>
            <div class='column ui-droppable col-md-6'></div>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
var tempString = "<div class='draggable'>" +
                "<div class='row'>" +
                    "<div class='column drop-container ui-droppable col-md-6'></div>" +
                    "<div class='column ui-droppable col-md-6'></div>" +
                "</div>" +
            "</div>"

$(function () {
$("#draggable, .draggable").draggable({
    revert: "invalid",
    greedy:true,
    connectToSortable: ".MainWrapper, .ui-droppable",
    helper: function () {
        return tempString
    },
    start: function (event, ui) {
        $(ui.helper).css("width", "100%").css("height", "auto");
    }
});



$(".ui-droppable").droppable({
    greedy: true,
    drop: function (event, ui) {

    }
}).sortable();
```

Edit: Here is a Fiddle of my code - https://jsfiddle.net/crwfgeox/2/ 
I don't use Fiddle so I am not sure how to get Draggable working on it. On my local machine it is dragging but I have the two problems mentioned above.

Comment: Please create a working example that shows the problem you have.

Comment: Sure here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/crwfgeox/2/ but I can't get draggable working at all on Fiddler

Comment: your fiddle is not working...continue in this and try to reproduce your issue..https://plnkr.co/edit/IgMM5rgHAtm2isuSS4IP?p=preview

Comment: I have been trying ot get it working on that but I cannot for the life of me even get it to where I have it locally. I will continue working locally and post an answer as and when I get there :)